# didn't download .csv in laravel (php)?

Tags: php, laravel-5, export-to-csv

I am new in laravel, when I hit my code then it's given response in browser like 
output:
    ID,"Event Name"
    1,"test event"
    3,"test test 1"

please see my below code and guide me =>

```
$events = Events::all()->toArray();
        $event_set = array();

        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($events); die;
        $i =0;
        foreach ($events as $event)
        {
            $record['id'] = $event['id'];
            $record['event_name'] = $event['event_name'];
            $event_set[$i] = $record;
            $i++;
        }

        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($event_set); die('test');
        $filename = "events.csv";

        $header = ['ID', 'Event Name'];
        $export_data = $this->getDataCsv($event_set, $header);
        return response($export_data)
            ->header('Content-Type','application/csv')
            ->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
            ->header('Expires','0');


function getDataCsv($data, $headers, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"') {


        $filename = "php://temp";
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
        fputcsv($fp, $headers, $delimiter, $enclosure);
        if(count($data)>0){
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                fputcsv($fp, $value, $delimiter, $enclosure);
            }
        }
        rewind($fp);
        $csvdata = fread($fp, 1048576);
        fclose($fp);
        return rtrim($csvdata, "\n");
    }
```

please suggest me, what I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

use this function to generate and download CSV file

pass data as:

```
$data = [
        ['ID', 'Event Name', 'test event'], // this is going to be header for the csv file
        [1, 'xyz', 'aadfas'],
        [2, 'abc', 'jljljl'],
    ];
```

and call this function

```
public function arrayToCSVDonwload($data, $fileName = null, $delimiter = ",")
{

    $fileName = $fileName ? $fileName . '.csv' : microtime(true) . ".csv";

    header("Content-Type: application/csv");
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row, $delimiter);
    }
    fclose($output);
    exit;
}
```